SQLAgent high number of handles
We have an Azure VM with SQL Server (SQL Server on Azure Virtual Machines).
When investigating small disconnections from our signalR service running on that server we have seen that SQLAGENT.EXE has many handles open. In this case 148.000 sometimes 300.000 or 400.000.

Is this normal? What could be the reason this number is so high?
Is SQLAGENT.exe required?
Can we safely disable it to give back the resources to our server or is it needed for Azure (because of this special SQL Server on Azure Virtual Machines type)?

Task Manager is usually a bad way to gauge if your SQL Server instance has issues. SQL Server is like a mini-OS managing its own system resources internally, to optimize performance. I don't think anyone can tell if you it's necessarily abnormal or a bad thing if the SQL Agent process has 400k handles at a given time (though I imagine it's related to whatever the Jobs that Agent is currently running and the resources those Jobs consume). You should start with tools like sp_WhoIsActive and sp_PressureDetector instead.
